# Apache Camel Data mapping to store data

Tags: apache, bind, data-mapping

I am new to the Apache camel.

Can someone please help me with some data mapping example for the below scenario.

I have a camel route which reads a large text file delimited with '|' (pipe) and each new record delimited with '\n' (new line).
Now I want store this data to the corresponding TABLES. I know the order which data goes to which column in which table (tables have relationships). But I am not sure how to map this data.

What is the approach how to achieve this?.

Input file format

```
 id|name|semester|java
 1|ABC|1st|80|
 
 1   - column1 TableA
 ABC - coulmn2 TableA
 1st - coulmn1 TableB
 80  - coulmn1 TableC
```